# WindowManager for all activities in an application

Tags: android, view, android-windowmanager

My end goal is to use WindowManager and add views to it that will persist across my entire app (without using `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` that requires a special permission from the user in API >=23).

What I do currently is this:

1. Register ActivityLifecyclerCallback when that app launches
2. Add the views I want to persist to the windowManager and keep a list of them on the side.
3. Every time an activity is resumed I do this:

   1. get the WindowManager of the current activity by calling `currentActivity.getWindowManager()`
   2. reinflate and recall `wm.addView(..)` to all the windows that were added before.

However, no matter what I do the windows never get added when calling `addView`, its like the window manager just ignores that call..

I am using TYPE_APPLICATION for the windows.

I tried using `currentActivity.getSystemService(WINDOW_MANAGER)` instead of `currentActivity.getWindowManager()`

Can anybody tell why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to all beliefs `TYPE_APPLICATION_ATTACHED_WINDOW` or `TYPE_APPLICATION` or anything that with the word `APPLICATION` in it (which makes sense by the way) is **NOT** the way to go.

I have no idea why and if a *Google engineer* is here to answer that would be great but the solution is to use `TYPE_TOAST` *(?!?!?)*

Also make sure you get a new `WindowManager` instance from the new activity when switching between activities so if you add windows or remove them it is a valid instance.

Thanks about it.. 4 hours wasted over *naming conventions* and *lack of good documentation* :)